# Moving Right When Dragging Formula Down

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a SUMIF formula as follows: `=SUMIF($B$2:$B$5758,">1",N$2:N$5758)`

Is it possible to make it so that when this formula is copied down the formula becomes `=SUMIF($C$2:$C$5758,">1",N2:N5758)` and so on?

Comment: That’s not what Copy Down does. You could achieve something similar with some coordinate functions. Or simply rethink what you want to do. ;)

Comment: Copy down meaning the B changes to C? and in the next row C changes to D?

Comment: @datatoo That's right.  Essentially changing things so that Excel thinks it's moving right instead of down.  I was thinking the OFFSET function might help here but I'm not sure how to use it in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`INDEX` function makes this easy to do. Let's assume that you don't want to reference any columns further left than column `Z` (adjust as required) and that the start cell for the first formula is `A2` (adjust as required) then you can use this formula in `A2` copied down

`=SUMIF(INDEX($B$2:$Z$5758,0,ROWS(A$2:A2)),">1",N$2:N$5758)`

`INDEX` with zero as the row reference returns the whole column, the specific column is determined by `ROWS` function which increments by 1 each row as you copy down so moves one column to the right each time.

`INDEX` is normally preferable to any solution using `OFFSET` or `INDIRECT` because those two functions are volatile - meaning that the formula re-calculates every time anything in the worksheet is re-calculated

Comment: This does seem more elegant, and not having a volatile formula is a better approach. Thanks for a better answer

Answer (score 3):

You can try something like this
It adjusts the column value based upon the row position, but you can adapt it to your starting position
in A2

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,ROW()+1)&":"&ADDRESS(5758,ROW()+1)),">1",$N$2:$N$5758)
```

If column N needs adjusting also for the sumif do the same with that 
in A3

```
=SUMIF(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,ROW()+1)&":"&ADDRESS(5758,ROW()+1)),">1",INDIRECT(ADDRESS(2,ROW()+12)&":"&ADDRESS(5758,ROW()+12)))
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier solution, just make the formulas and drag them to the right, lock the rows ( with $ sign) and then copy and "paste transpose" them on the place you want.