# A formula that moves to the right when dragged down

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a SUM formula as follows:

```
=SUM(Monday!B5+Tuesday!B5+Wednesday!B5+Thursday!B5+Friday!B5+Saturday!B5+Sunday!B5)
```

Is it possible to make it so that when this formula is copied down the formula becomes:

```
=SUM(Monday!C5+Tuesday!C5+Wednesday!C5+Thursday!C5+Friday!C5+Saturday!C5+Sunday!C5)
```

and so on?

Comment: Possible duplicate:  https://superuser.com/questions/804772/moving-right-when-dragging-formula-down

Comment: YES, it's very much possible. Either if you copy of drag the Formula Right. Remember  it's basic rule of Excel.

Comment: @RajeshS OP is asking to drag downwards but change COL references; i.e. =A1 when dragged down changes to A2, but OP wants B1

Answer (score 0):

You asked that how to copy formula A1 **down**, but force it to change to B1 instead of standard expected A2. Somehow we need to ask excel to move down but count sideways; i.e. move from row 1 to row 2; but count Columns from A to B.

I assume that only the Column references are going to change, the Sheet Names (Days) are going to stay same. & your start cell is A1.

Multiple ways to do this. One could be using the char codes i.e. converting numbers to Alphabets. `=code("A")` is 65 & so on.

`=CHAR(65+ROW()-1)&1` will be translated as:

```
=CHAR(65+ROW()-1)&1
=CHAR(65+1-1)&1
=CHAR(66-1)&1
=CHAR(65)&1
=CHAR(65)&1
="A"&1
=A1
```

Assuming you are in A1, B5 can also be written as =CHAR(65+ROW()+1-1)&5

Note that I assume you are starting from Column A; -1 denotes Column A; so if you Start from B, use -2. 65 is code of A.

Use this formula in your first/starting cell, replacing every B5 with `=CHAR(65+COLUMN()+1-1)&5`.

`ROW()` bit will increase as you move down; but `CHAR` bit will translate it to column identifiers i.e.`A,B,C...` Also, the fixed parts i.e. strings in formula need to be enclosed in quotes.

```
=SUM(
  Monday!B5+
  Tuesday!B5+
  Wednesday!B5+
  Thursday!B5+
  Friday!B5+
  Saturday!B5+
  Sunday!B5
 )
```

becomes (`B` gets replaced by `&CHAR(65+ROW())&`)

```
=SUM(
  "Monday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5+
  "Tuesday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5+
  "Wednesday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5+
  "Thursday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5+
  "Friday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5+
  "Saturday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5+
  "Sunday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5
 )
```

But this will just give a string an error  of #value because it will try to add word Monday & B5. We need to enclose each line in INDIRECT().

**Final Formula**

```
=SUM(
  INDIRECT("Monday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5)+
  INDIRECT("Tuesday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5)+
  INDIRECT("Wednesday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5)+
  INDIRECT("Thursday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5)+
  INDIRECT("Friday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5)+
  INDIRECT("Saturday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5)+
  INDIRECT("Sunday!"&CHAR(65+ROW())&5)
 )
```

Let me know of any questions.

*Note, this might not be the fastest / shortest method. Excel, like any other software, has multiple ways of doing same thing.*

Answer (score -1):

*I would like to suggest you the Formula will help you to SUM the next Column instead of the Row while you DRAG it DOWN.*

***Check the Screen Shot below.***

[image]

Now let me explain the  scenario first.

*Data Range I've used is M1:N8 and Sheets are 8 & 9.*

**NB: Formulas are written in Sheet8.**

The Cell M9 (Red Colour) has Formula,

=SUM(Sheet8!M1+Sheet9!M1).

**Cell M11** (Blue Colour) has **Value 48** and the Formula is,

```
=SUM(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET($M$1,{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7},ROWS(M$11:M11)-1,{1},1)))
```

**NB:** *This Formula is adding data from M1:M8, if you want to Sum Range of Cells.*

*When you Drag this Formula down, will get the sum of Column N.*

Now finally, **Cell M14** (Green Colour) has **Value 40** and the formula is,

```
=SUM(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(Sheet8!$M$1,{0},ROWS(M$14:M14)-1,{1},1))+SUM(SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(Sheet9!$M$1,{0},ROWS(M$14:M14)-1,{1},1))))
```

**NB:** *This formula is getting **the SUM of M1 from both Sheet8 and Sheet9**.
         When you DRAG it down it pick values of **Cell N1 from both Sheets**.*

*Hope this help you. I've posted the solution after it was tested by me.*

Comment: Better put the reason,, somebody voted Negative !!